# Update URL in browser while scrolling a page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling page in React. Let's say the page is split into 4 sections:

- Who we are
- About
- Members
- Alumni

So on scrolling, if it's at the section 'Members' with the id=members the URL should be updated to:
website.com/who-we-are#members so he can copy this link, and when you access this URL to send you directly to that section.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to determine if a section is in the viewport. Use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) as target. Use an [Effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to create the IntersectionObserver.

Then you can update the location per [`document.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). You can also use e.g. the convenient [`useHistory()` hook of React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

Answer (score 0):

Because the React Router library [has changed](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) since this was last answered, I'd like to add a new answer.

First, wrap your main page in a [Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/routers/picking-a-router) (for most web use cases, a [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.15.0/routers/picking-a-router) will work). In my case, I put in right in the root (main.tsx):

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render 
(
   <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
   </React.StrictMode>
 );
```

Then, arrange for navigation to your page's sections. To use React's navigation hook, call `useNavigate('/route')` or use React Router's `Link` component (use this instead of a native `<a href...` to avoid reloading the page upon navigation):

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/route'}}>Route</Link>
```

Finally, use a React hook to listen for location changes and scroll to the element you want:

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  const el = document.getElementById('my_element');
  el && window.scrollTo({ 
    behavior: 'smooth', 
    top: el.offsetTop 
  });
}, [location]);
```